# Springboot read json and create menu link out of it

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I need to read a json file with multiple linkname and url then create a menu link mapping out of it.

Menu

linkname1: [This is a link1](https://stackoverflow.com)

linkname2: [This is a link2](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Using org.apache.model.rest.RestDefinition method if possible, any idea?

Comment: I found a way to do this with my another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73254189/pretty-print-json-with-spring-boot-only-works-with-console) with thymeleaf.

Answer (score 0):

I have to put

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/xxxx")
```

On the main class

I have to put

```
@GetMapping()
public static RestDefinition
```

But it only run in eclipse and it compile with no error, but if you run, you will have error.  I just decided to rewrite it all in spring-boot without RestDefinition and old java programs.